# tableview.cellforrow(at indexpath) return nil in didselectrowat ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

I tried to find the cell that is selected. In `didSelectRowAt` function. But the `cellForRowAt` returns nil value.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    guard let _ = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? ChatListTableViewCell else {
        return }
   }
```

Comment: please show code of `cellForRowAtIndex` method

Comment: Use `UITableView`'s `indexPathForSelectedRow` method.

Comment: Did you verify that the `cellForRow` function really returns nil? The guard let could potentially also fail because the cell that was found couldn't be cast to a `ChatListTableViewCell`.